# How to fetch data from Recycler View and perform calculations on it?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]

This is my recycler view . I am displaying the expense related information of different people . All the data is stored in the string form ( including the "**total amount**" and "**amount paid**" fields).

I want to sum the total amount i.e , I want to add all the data that is present in the "**total amount**" column .

I also want to store expense information of each person . I want to know how much each person has paid . For example , in the recycler view , a user " sadaf" has her details added three times ; one for daal , one for dahi and one for water.

So , I want to add her amount paid(50+10+5) . I want to do this for every user and store the information for every user

Gulati ji :  50

Amen : 55

Sadaf : 65

CALCULATONADAP.java

```
        calcuationAdap = new CalcuationAdap(Calculation.this,data);
        for (int i = 0 ;i<data.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(data.get(i).getItem());
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(calcuationAdap);
        calcuationAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray jsonArray= jsonObject.getJSONArray("kharche");

        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
        {
            SetExpenseModel setExpenseModel = new SetExpenseModel();
            JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                String user_name=jsonObject1.getString("USER_NAME");
                String item=jsonObject1.getString("ITEM");
                String total_amount=jsonObject1.getString("TOT_AMT");
                String date=jsonObject1.getString("DATE");
                String my_amount=jsonObject1.getString("MY_AMT");
                String desc=jsonObject1.getString("DESC");

                setExpenseModel.setItem(item);
                setExpenseModel.setUser_name(user_name);
                setExpenseModel.setTot_amt(total_amount);
                setExpenseModel.setMy_amt(my_amount);
                setExpenseModel.setDate(date);
                setExpenseModel.setDesc(desc);


            data.add(setExpenseModel);
        }
        int main_total = "0";
        calcuationAdap = new CalcuationAdap(Calculation.this,data);
        for (int i = 0 ;i<data.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(data.get(i).getItem());
            main_total = main_total + Integer.parseInt(data.get(i).getMy_amt());
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(main_total ), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(calcuationAdap);
        calcuationAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thank you .This helped me a lot but I also want to know how can I store total expense of every user shown in the recycler view . Should I use a hash map but the problem is that my users name are not unique .for example---sadaf paid(50+10+5)=65..  and amen paid(50+5)=55 and gulatiji paid(50)...